Python Selenium TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
I keep getting this error when try to run my code. I'm new to Python Selenium and I just can't get my head around this error:
TypeError: practicepagebutton() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Test_e2e file:
from pageObjects.HomePage import HomePage
from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage
from pageObjects.PracticePage import PracticePage
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import pytest
import time


class TestAutomation(BaseClass):
    def test_e2e(self):
        homepage = HomePage(self.driver)
        practicePage = HomePage.practicepagebutton()-------------> getting error on this line
        practicePage.getPageTitle()
        loginpage = PracticePage.testLoginPage()
        loginpage.loginUsername().send_keys("student")
        loginpage.loginPassword().send_keys("Password123")
        loginpage.loginSubmit().click()

HomePage.py:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from pageObjects.PracticePage import PracticePage


class HomePage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    practice = (By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Practice']")

    def practicepagebutton(self):
        self.driver.find_element(*HomePage.practice).click()
        practicePage = PracticePage(self.driver)
        return practicePage

PracticePage.py:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage

class PracticePage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    testLoginPageButton = (By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Test Login Page']")
    def getPageTitle(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*PracticePage.testLoginPageButton).title()

    def testLoginPage(self):
        self.driver.find_element(*PracticePage.testLoginPageButton).click()
        loginpage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        return loginpage

LoginPage.py:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Error:
test_e2e.py::TestAutomation::test_e2e 

============================== 1 failed in 4.03s ==============================
FAILED                             [100%]
test_e2e.py:15 (TestAutomation.test_e2e)
self = <test_e2e.TestAutomation object at 0x000002593CA5DE20>

    def test_e2e(self):
        homepage = HomePage(self.driver)
>       practicePagee = HomePage.practicepagebutton()
E       TypeError: practicepagebutton() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

test_e2e.py:18: TypeError

Process finished with exit code 1

Could someone please help me with this error?

This question is similar to: Why do I get "TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem is that you're using the class directly, instead of creating an instance of the class.
Do this instead:
hp = HomePage(self.driver)
practicePagee = hp.practicepagebutton()

